# Nesting cypher queries with a collection

Tags: neo4j

I have a linked list of Events in Neo4J with a :NEXT relationship.  I can retrieve a aggregated collection of the next 3 Events with:

```
MATCH (e:Event {eventType:”123”}),
path  = (e)-[:NEXT*3]->()
RETURN [node IN nodes(path) | node.eventType] as et, count(*) as count 
ORDER BY count DESC LIMIT 10
```

I have the textual descriptions of the event types in EventDetail nodes connected via:

MATCH (e:Event {eventType:”123”})-[:DETAILS]->(ed:EventDetails)  RETURN ed.description LIMIT 1

Is there a way of nesting these and getting the ed.description property back from the first query? thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This should return the description for every `Event` node with `eventType: '123'` in a single query.

```
// if every event has EventDetails then match up front
MATCH (e:Event {eventType:”123”})-[:DETAILS]->(ed:EventDetails)
// you can use the with clause to pass the nodes to teh next section where you match the path
WITH e, ed
MATCH path=e-[:NEXT*3]->() 
RETURN [node IN nodes(path) | node.eventType] as et
, ed.description
,count(*) as count 
ORDER BY count DESC LIMIT 10
```

Adjusting the above query to get return event details for every node in the path rather than just the first node.

```
// match paths of events in chains of four nodes 
// that start with eventtype 123
MATCH p=(:Event {eventType:”123”})-[:NEXT*3]->(:Event)
WITH nodes(p) as events
// loop through the events in the path
UNWIND events AS e 
// find the event details for each event
MATCH e-[:DETAILS]->(ed:EventDetails)
WITH [e.eventType, ed.description] as event_detail    
RETURN event_detail, count(*) as count 
ORDER BY count DESC LIMIT 10
```

Comment: Wasn't thinking that way, thanks very much Dave.  What this does return though is just the description of the eventtype "123" whereas I was looking for the descriptions of all three previous events.

Comment: Yes, that is correct. Sorry, i was not following that each node in the path was also an event. I will add an an additional query that does what you would like.

Comment: Sorry Dave, that new query is really useful but I realised I phrased my first question badly.  If Event 123 is “Shopping”, Event 124=“Work”, Event 125=“Eat”, Event 126=“Sleep” my original query produced the top 10 most popular series of events e.g. {123,124,126  = 1000, 125,124,126 = 800, 123,124,123 = 600 etc}  I was trying to match those nodes in the collection to the connected EventDetails node to make the report more readable e.g. {Shopping, Work, Sleep = 1000, Shopping, Work, Shopping = 800 etc} sort of like you might use a LEFT JOIN for in SQL but for the nodes of the collection.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this:

```
MATCH (e:Event {eventType:”123”}), path = (e)-[:NEXT*3]->() 
WITH [node IN nodes(path) | id(node)] as et, count(*) as count 
MATCH (e)-[:DETAILS]->(ed) WHERE id(e) IN et
RETURN et, COLECT(ed), count 
ORDER BY count DESC LIMIT 10
```